# Will this homopolar motor self rotate in a vacuum?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, physics, interstellar-travel

Is it convenient to ask about the motor from the link:
[Roller Homopolar Motor](https://www.google.com/search?q=Roller%20homopolar%20motor&sxsrf=APwXEdcwa4omxuRI7IQf51yYF7jMGlfPvg:1682923503665&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF1vrMwtP-AhUkRPEDHUtVAFYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=568&dpr=1#imgrc=QhyId1tELom-pM)

When it is on the table, the motor rotates freely, together with the attached conductor.

Will the upper motor in the picture self rotate in a vacuum?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Maybe Not

The classic homopolar motor will spin like any other motor in zero G, with the two halves spinning in opposite directions, due to [conservation of momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation), then as it runs flat and friction turns battery energy into heat will slow down until it returns to rest in the starting condition.

The same mechanical principle of spinning up a mass to apply a counter rotation is used to control spacecraft via [momentum wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel) but they generally use conventional electric motors and are part of larger reaction control systems.

The video linked in a later [edit](https://youtu.be/rl9hXn2fseU?t=68) is an interesting case since it does not appear to be a classic motor since it is portrayed as being a single fixed assembly that rolled itself as a unit. The video quality is too low to make out why, and in comments the video producer notes it only worked once out of several trys, with very low torque and they had not expected it to work themselves as it is missing the stator and rotor that make a full motor assembly. Assuming the video is in fact legitimate this may mean this particular device relies on gravity to produce motion (possibly through the batteries pulling off center), and therefore would not spin in space.

Comment: Thank you. So If we leave it somewhere in Space without external forces. It will rotate ? Untill the Battery has Charge to generate current.

Comment: Together with the Conductor , just like the Upward .

Comment: @user51174 if the design spins on earth, it will spin in space. If the design is just a short circuit because it does not have current flow across the magnetic field it will work in neither location. Looking at the upper photo it does not appear to have current flow across the magnetic field so it is not a motor and will just get hot.

Comment: @ GremlinWranger. Thank you. The design id electric current , that is crossing magnetic field. The same is on the picture.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Roller%20homopolar%20motor&sxsrf=APwXEdcwa4omxuRI7IQf51yYF7jMGlfPvg:1682923503665&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF1vrMwtP-AhUkRPEDHUtVAFYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=568&dpr=1#imgrc=QhyId1tELom-pM

Comment: @user51174 have found what you are looking at, but you are linking to the google search you used, suggest next time using a link to the actual site or image.